# Snapping tool issues on QGIS 3.12: Virtual polygons between two edges

Tags: snapping, qgis-3

I am digitizing land use inside some cadastral parcels. I have two polygon layers, one for the parcels, and one for land use. Since I don't want to digitize outside the parcels, I used the snapping tool, with the parcel layer checked, snapping to segments and vertices, tolerance 12.

I also checked land use layer, same tolerance, snapping to segments and vertices, and checked 'avoid intersect' to be able to go faster. So I filled out my parcels, making sure to snap each time, etc... At the end though, to check that I had left no holes, I copied my features from my parcel layers, and pasted them in my landuse layer. Since the 'avoid intersect' is checked, it shouldn't be able to copy anything if there is no hole.

However it did copy stuff. When I filter for the new features added, this is what I see, in a lot of places:

[image]

Lines, with two or more vertices (red segments. here the cross at the top means there is two vertices at this end). When I zoom in to the maximum, I still see a line, not a polygon. And this line correspond to a shared edge between two adjacent polygons from my land use layer.

Has anyone already experienced this? It is not that bothering for what I intend to do, but for the future, I'd like to know if I'm using the tool wrong, or if it's just a known issue...